# Strobogrammatic Numbers

Tags: code-golf, number

## Strobogrammatic Numbers

---

#### Definition

A number which is rotationally symmetrical, i.e., it'll appear the same when rotated by 180 deg in the plane of your screen. The following figure illustrates it better,

[image: strobogrammatic-number]

(source: w3resource.com)

## Task

Given a number as the input, determine if it's strobogrammatic or not.

## Examples

- Truthy

```
1
8
0
69
96
69169
1001
666999
888888
101010101
```

- Falsey

```
2
3
4
5
7
666
969
1000
88881888
969696969
```

## Rules

- The number is guaranteed to be less than a billion.
- We are considering `1` in it's roman numeral format for the sake of the challenge.
- Input can be taken as number, or an array of chars, or as string.
- Output would be a truthy/falsey value. However, you are allowed to flip the output values.
- This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes will win!

---

[Sandbox link](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20557/83605)

Comment: I think you should clarify which digits are rotationally symmetric with each other.  The only way to figure it out right now is from the examples.

Answer (score 3):

## Node.js 11.6.0,  <s>34</s>  33 bytes

Expects an array of digits. Returns *false* for strobogrammatic, or *true* otherwise.

```javascript
n=>n.some(c=>n.pop()-c**66%79%63)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDNDoIwEITvPkYTkpaEphVd6AGPPoE35EAq@BNsCUUTn74KetDEbffS9JuZbOdS32unh3M/JsYeGt8W3hQbw529NlRPt972lCU6jgGiTEWQMq@tcbZreGePlJS74TaeHhVhi@/3lpaccyJJxf6CHAMCA6AwogD3SNwmhUDXAwClUGc@Hzz3M7PgR0H2ptzWncPqWmKZKQZWGFhjIAv8GW841KII9SQDTb1i3zMJ/BM)

#### How?

Taking the precision errors on large integers into account<sup>1</sup>, we look for a function:

$$f(x)=(x^p\bmod m_0)\bmod m_1$$

such that:

$$f(0)=0,\:f(1)=1,\:f(6)=9,\:f(8)=8,\:f(9)=6$$

and:

$$f(x)>9\text{ for }x\in\{2,3,4,5,7\}$$

*<sub>1: [These errors actually depend on the JS engine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65426364). This is guaranteed to work with Node 11.6.0.</sub>*

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 38 bytes

Expects an array of digits. Returns *false* for strobogrammatic, or *true* otherwise.

```javascript
n=>n.some(c=>n.pop()!="01----9-86"[c])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZC9DsIgFIV338I7wVAC/iAMdfQJ3LBDg60/qdCUauLTY1sdNPFy70L4zjmBcy0fZbDdpe0z549VrPPo8q1jwd8qYsdT61tC5zlwkQ2jMyXB2IJG613wTcUafyJg9t29Pz8LoLPv@5oYxhgIKOhfoDDAMSA1RrTEPQK3Cc7R50kptUadaho897OT4EcBB2d2ZROwuhZY5hIDKwysMbBJ/BlvONUiT/UkEk0Nse8dBfEF)

Comment: The conditions say `However, you are allowed to flip the output values.` So it seems to me that `!` can be removed and save one byte

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pa`, <s>48</s> 34 bytes

@Arnauld had a better idea in his JavaScript answer than my first one in Perl, so I stole it.

```perl
y/0-9/01aaaa9a86/;$_="@F"==reverse
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LUvBCsIwFLvnK6TsOvee2trnGHgSPPgNo4cehLGVbQr7eeubMyEhhCTFsbN5Cou59@k1X3ZFa@q8VFRKRRwUEryr6qJtzPVmmmaM7zhOMecDjjjB4gznHMQJmIjgFaxam41geBA0iFPnbcnrTUR@B50z/QlLnyHNz6Gfcvmwe@1ymbrwBQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
•yΘOñ•I<èRQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOiynMz/A9vBDI8bQ6vCAr8/z/aTEfBMhYA)

*-1 byte thanks to Razetime's suggestion*

Takes the number as a list of digits

### Explained

```
•yΘOñ•       # Push the number 1000090860
      I<     # Decrement the input list
        èR   # And get each number when rotated 180 degrees, reversing it
          Q  # Check if that equals the input
```

Comment: You realise this beats your existing answer to the dupe, right?

Comment: Lol I managed to outgolf Adnan twice

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-n`, 30 bytes

```ruby
p$_.==$_.reverse.tr'92-7','69'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0AlXs/WFkgUpZalFhWn6pUUqVsa6Zqr66ibWar//29pBoX/8gtKMvPziv/r5gEA)

Comment: You may require just an extra `-l` flag to make it work for multiline inputs! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 53 bytes

```python
lambda n:["01....9.86"[int(c)]for c in n[::-1]]==[*n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/BDoIwDIbvPsXSE5hINtHJSLj6BN7GDoghkGAhOA88/QQxwY729LX/3/ztR1t3GLsqy11bPO@PgmGqgYtoKhUlEnSDNihDU3UDK1mDDHWaHoQxWab3aFw/zAK4DW9bjxDuFq4CEBD@UUKIE5KKoJLeVngCwTk9LqVUimqSb3m2X69TyPFatK8596o7EldM6EToTOjiZ/K@2jzBN4mFn3lyLT1N3Qc)